# How to add a custom element to the recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with data. I tried to add a custom first element.

```
 if(position == 0) {
        Trend item = items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        int i = 0;
        items.add(i, item);
 }


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) return 1;
    else return 2;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   if (viewType == 1) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_trendsnewuser, parent, false));
    } else {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_trends, parent, false));
    }
```

I am duplicating now the first element twice.
How to add a custom row with my custom options?

Comment: If I am to understand correctly, you need the first UI element to look differently than the rest of them, overriding the viewholder that you specified?

Comment: but in the onBindViewHolder method i cant make a new, just duplicate a first row..

Comment: Include your full  adapter code.

Comment: You need to add an element to elements collection and notify the RV with `notifyiteminserted` method. The logic for adding the element should not depend on position displayed but should be bound to some data event of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You should create Two ViewHolder with different views and In ItemViewType check for specific position and according to that Inflate specific ViewHolder.

Here is Some code for this.

```
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (products.size()==0){
            return 0;
        }else if (products.get(position)== 0){
            return 0;
        }else
            return 1;
        }
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
```

And ViewHolder:

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    if (viewType== 0){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.FIRSTTIMEVIEW,parent,false);
        return new MovieViewHolder(view);
    }else if (viewType==1)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.OTHERVIEWS,parent,false);
        return new OtherViewHolder(view);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: i already done that, i have a different layout, The problem is i dont know how to develop a custom item, not duplicate it..

Comment: you mean for every item you need custom layout?

Comment: just for the first